# Quick and easy web automation/data scraping

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, internet-explorer, automation

I need to enter around 3 pieces of data into a website I don't own, press submit, and scrape a few pieces of data.  I need to repeat this using different dates around 50 times. I've done this before for stuff I've reused a lot with Powershell.  However, I was wondering if there was something simple like point and click I could use as if I spend hours on this I could have just as easily typed in the data and copied the results into a spreadsheet.

Any browser will do.

Comment: This question is off-topic, but you should look at a selenium-based approach: https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: If you can capture the request and form data, you could modify that and send it instead of using the webpage.

Comment: Is that a public site?

Comment: Yes. It is a public site. It is a travel site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use IE automation using VBA to scrape the data from IE and paste it in to Excel Workbook.

Example:

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
 
    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True
 
    'Define URL
    URL = "https://www.example.com"
 
    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL
 
    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
 
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
 
    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"
    
    'Unload IE
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

References:

(1) [Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)

(2) [VBA Web Scraping with GetElementsByTagName](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-web-scraping-with-getelementsbytagname/)

(3) [IE (Internet Explorer) Automation using Excel VBA](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml)

Further, You can try to modify the code based on your requirement.